# titanium alloy open view from button

Tags: titanium-alloy

After being away from Titanium for awhile, seems I forgot even the simplest tasks. Case in point: I have a stack of buttons on a main page. Each button should open its respective view when clicked. How do I open that associated view when the button is clicked?

View

```
<Alloy>
<Tab title="Home">
    <Window class="container">
        <Label>This is the Home View</Label>
        <ImageView id="kplLogo"/>
        <View id="homeNav">
            <Button class="navButton" id="recognizeButton" title="Recognize" onClick="doClick" />
            <Button class="navButton" id="reactButton" title="React"/>
            <Button class="navButton" id="reportButton" title="Report"/>

        </View>
    </Window>
</Tab>
</Alloy>
```

When the user clicks a button, such as the recognizeButton for now, it should open the recognizeView. I know it's simple, but I'm having brainlock at the moment.

Thanks for the help. Ask if you need more detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, add a property to each Button which will make possible to invoke the child View controllers, such as:

```
<Button id="recognizeButton" title="Recognize" child_controller="recognizeView" />
```

Also use an id on the `<tab>` element:

```
<Tab id="hometab">
```

Then, in the controller, add the event listener:

```
$.recognizeButton.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (e.source.child_controller) {
      controller = Alloy.createController(e.source.child_controller);
      $.hometab.open(controller.getView());
    }
});
```

This will open a new window in the same tab, preserving history so that when you click reutrn, you'll be back in the main tab. If you need a broader example, check this: https://github.com/asiviero/drupanium_app/tree/master/app in which I use the home view in that manner, opening up views from controllers inside "includes" folder

Comment: I appreciate your response. I tried the code, as is, but nothing happened when I clicked the button. I put an alert in the listener, but it never fired. At least I'm not getting an error. So, some progress has been made. Thanks. Let me know if you have any further suggestions.

Comment: If you haven't added any styling yet, it may be the case you're not clicking on the right button since they're piled up. Have you tried with a single button instead of all of them?

Comment: Found out the problem and I'm editing my original answer to fix it. Basically it needs to ask child_controller from e.source instead of purely e.

Comment: It's closer, but not quite right yet. This line $.homeTab.open(controller.getView()); triggers the error Invalid type passed to function in homeView.js (line 83). So it's not liking the getView() as a parameter.

Comment: Perhaps the problem is now in the child view, there're some restrictions to top-level components in Alloy so they can be rendered. Could you share the child view code?

Comment: Try removing the `<Tab>` element from the child view so it's top level element is an `<Window>`.

Comment: That was the answer! Give the developer a cookie! You win.

Comment: As a clarification, `Ti.Ui.Tab.open()` receives a `Window` object as a parameter and opens it on top of the rendering stack. If you wish to do the same but from a `Window` object, take a look at this: https://gist.github.com/asiviero/7347533

Comment: Dude! I'm so glad I reread this post. I've been spinning my wheels on this very problem you coded in your gist. +1 again!